# Check if a MySQL database has any stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to figure out the best way to determine if a mysql database uses stored procs or not.  It's not a home grown database... open source stuff. 
I found another post here:  [Find all MySQL Stored Procedure calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926967/find-all-mysql-stored-procedure-calls)

Based on that post, I've tried the following:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.ROUTINES
    -> ; Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Can I safely assume then that this database has no stored procs?
Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are 'root' I think you can only assume that there are no procs that you have access to.

Answer (score 1):

With the Query you posted, you are correct in making that assumption. I tested it on a local database with no Stored Procs and got the same result. I created a test stored proc, re-ran that same query and got a single result (with the proc I created).